# angular routing with multiple modules and dynamic routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've an Angular (4) app with the following structure:

```
app.module
   bi.module
   auth.module
```

The routing should be:

```
/ -> redirect to /home
/home -> use HomeComponent
/auth -> redirect to /auth/login
/auth/login -> use LoginComponent
/auth/register -> use RegisterComponent
any other thing -> use PageComponent
```

The thing is that this routing is splitted into different modules and I'm also using lazy loading so that the bi.module is only loaded when needed (after user is logged in, basically).
Now, my auths routes are working and if I type /home this is also working, but the empty / or any other ones are not working.

This is my app.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: './bi/bi.module#BiModule'
  }
];

...

imports: [
    ...
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }),
    BiModule
  ],
```

My auth.module is working fine, so no need for it.
My bi.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: {
      content: PageResolve
    }
  }
];

...

imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
```

When I go '/', my wildcard route in biModule is activated and my PageComponent is rendered instead of redirecting to /home.

This is my trace from the router:

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/"}
Router Event: RoutesRecognized
RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'', path:'**') } )
RoutesRecognized {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
Router Event: NavigationEnd
NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/')
NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/"}

PageComponent
```

The last trace (PageComponent) is a console.log in my component.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: When you say they are not working, how are they not working? Are they generating an error? I see you have tracing enabled, what is the trace saying when it does not work?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route that you have defined in the bi.module has a path of `""`. This will conflict with your home route which also has a path of `""`.

When you add your routes in the bi.module using `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` this prepends your new modules routes to the entire routes object. When you naviage to path `""`, angular finds the first path that matches the criteria, in this case it will be the PageComponent route. This is how the angular router is suppose to behave.

Every path in all routes must be unique, and therefore defining two routes with path `""` without a module prefix on the second will cause error.

https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration

It might not be possible to use the lazy loaded route as the wild card directly, but if you defined a wild card route in your app.module which redirected to the route in the bi.module you need, then this may redirect correctly.

I.E in app.module.

```
{
  path: '/bi',
  loadChildren: './bi/bi.module#BiModule'
},
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '/bi'
}
```

then in bi.module

```
{ path: 'bi', 
  children: [ { 
    path: '**', 
    component: PageComponent, 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }]
}
```

This does mean all routes in the bi module will be appended with the '/bi', but this is necessary to allow both `""` paths to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
As my first path defined is '' and redirects to /home I was assuming this should be the activated route, it's not very clear to me why this chooses the last option instead...

I like option 1, but I'd already test it and it made absolutely no change in the behaviour.
Option 2... I don´t like it, I should not need to create an additional url segment if I don´t need it.

Comment: Hmm yes, after I posted i had a look further and think the wildcard there may not work. Which component loads when you naviage to `""`?

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer, which should work as needed. the additional `/bi` segment would be needed.

Comment: I finally made it work with your suggestion, so using /bi in app.module and redirecting to the lazy loaded module. Then in bi.module I also need to use bi in the path, like this ```{
    path: 'bi',
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: PageComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ]
  }```
I'm happy to mark your question as a valid answer if you add the configuration for the bi.module.